# Retrieve data from outlook using c#.net

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to access tasks from a task manager type program, that will allow for tasks to be imported from outlook and displayed visually on screen.

I can display the task, but am having trouble retrieving any task out of outlook.

How can this be resolved?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this tutorial

http://geekswithblogs.net/TimH/archive/2006/05/26/79720.aspx

Worked well and found each of the different parts of each task usig the autocomplete within visual studio.

Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you connect your Outlook client to Microsoft Exchange Server you can access it's task list through webDAV.

See this forum thread:
http://objectmix.com/microsoft-exchange/269091-exchange-tasks-list-webdav.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about MS Outlook from MS Office package then this could be done via automation, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210897(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Visual Studio Tools for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d%28VS.80%29.aspx).  It's a .NET library that allows easy integration with all Office components.  It's the easiest way to do it from .NET.